# Limit for strings in node.js/express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, base64

I am sending a base64-encoded image as a string to my backend using node.js/express. I would like to store it in my Postgres database, but I can not fetch the string. Is there any limit to this?

Before reaching my AJAX call in frontend I fill the data with:

```
var data = {picture: ""};

const reader = new FileReader();
const get_picture = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //event handler
    reader.onload = resolve;
    reader.onerror = reject;
    //read image
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
})
.then(() => {
    data.picture = reader.result;
})
.catch(() => {
    show_modal(modal.title.error_custom, modal.body.error_image);
});

console.log(target_data);

$.ajax({ [...]
```

And my console show as expected:

```
Object { picture: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFIA…"}
```

This is by express route:

```
router.post("/upload_image", (req, res, next) => {
  const picture = req.body.picture;

  console.log("test");
  console.log(picture);
}
```

This shows an empty line in my backend console. Are there any limits to the size of the parameter? Or what am I doing wrong? Thanks

EDIT: this works with async/wait

```
$("#form").submit(async function (event) {
[...]
  var data = {picture: ""};

  const get_picture = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //event handler
    reader.onload = resolve;
    reader.onerror = reject;
    //read image
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  })
  .then(() => {
    data.picture = reader.result;
  })
  .catch(() => {
    show_modal(modal.title.error_custom, modal.body.error_image);
  });

  $.ajax({ [...]
```

Comment: have you include body-parser or equivalent in your nodejs application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax call doesn't wait for the reading process of your file, and send the top initialized object (var data = {picture: ""}).
You should call your ajax request in the `.then()`

```
var data = {picture: ""};

const reader = new FileReader();
const get_picture = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //event handler
    reader.onload = resolve;
    reader.onerror = reject;
    //read image
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
})
.then(() => {
    data.picture = reader.result;
    $.ajax({[...]});
})
.catch(() => {
    show_modal(modal.title.error_custom, modal.body.error_image);
});
```

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. I am still training on promises and async/await. I found another solution with making the whole function async and then using await for the promise.

Comment: What I don't get is why it was showing the right string in the console. It seems the code was continuing to the AJAX call without reader.result but jumping back to the console.log(data) including the fetched reader.result.

Comment: You have to delve deeper into how exactly does JS works. So is your problem solved?